# Django special order by in extra

Tags: mysql, django

How would I do the following `ORDER BY` in django?

```
instances = Catalog.objects.extra(order_by=('apple_id=%s DESC' %self.pk, 'apple_id'))
```

The result should be:

```
SELECT * FROM catalog ORDER BY (apple_id=%s DESC), apple_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
instances = Catalog.objects.extra(
               select={'ordering': "apple_id=%s" % self.pk}
             ).order_by('-ordering', 'pk')
```